# Маска для SKCropNode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

У меня возник вопрос, возможно ли инвертировать маску для `SKCropNode`?

Т.е. у меня есть текстура круга черного цвета с прозрачностью вокруг, которая будет маской для `SKCropNode`, и мне надо что бы вырезалось все не за кругом, а внутри круга. Т.е. то что прозрачно - показывать, то что не прозрачно - скрыть.

Comment: попробуй
circleMask.alpha = .0;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть область которая будет показываться с дыркой внутри (в данном случае - тот круг, который является маской).
Ставлю эту область сам низ по отношению к экрану, меняя ее zPosition (ставлю любое отрицательное значение, но возможно надо будет его подобрать чтобы не было слишком низко - в зависимости от кейса), затем на эту область я ставлю то что нужно вырезать с помощью маски - эта область находится выше, и уже после этого накладываю маску с фигуркой которую надо вырезать уже на эту область в которой zPosition больше.

```
override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    self.backgroundColor = SKColor.red

    let transparentScreen = SKSpriteNode(color: SKColor.black, size: size)
    transparentScreen.position = view.center
    transparentScreen.zPosition = 10
    transparentScreen.alpha = 0.6

    let mask = SKSpriteNode(color: SKColor.black, size: size) //Color dosn't matter
    mask.position = view.center
    mask.zPosition = 10
    mask.alpha = 1.0

    let circle = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: 50.0)
    circle.fillColor = SKColor.black //Color doesn't matter
    circle.lineWidth = 0.0
    circle.alpha = 1.0
    circle.blendMode = SKBlendMode.subtract

    mask.addChild(circle)

    let crop = SKCropNode()
    crop.maskNode = mask
    crop.addChild(transparentScreen)

    addChild(crop)
}
```

Результат:
[image: результат]